# VB6 Transaction within .NET transaction

Tags: c#, wcf, vb6

I have an ASP.NET WCF webservice that gets data from another service and save it in a database through a transaction. i.e. either all the data that comes is saved in database (commit) or nothing (rollback).

I need to add a new stage to the process of saving data in database, and that stage envolves invoking functions in a VB6 dll that also uses a transaction to connect to the same database. Is that possible?

here is the .NET code that is used to call VB6 function:

```
object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
ADODB.Recordset rsKR = new ADODB.Recordset();
rsKR.Fields.Append("F1", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adVarChar, 10, ADODB.FieldAttributeEnum.adFldFixed, null);
rsKR.Fields.Append("F2", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adVarChar, 10, ADODB.FieldAttributeEnum.adFldFixed, null);

rsKR.Open(oMissing, oMissing, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic,    ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic, -1);
rsKR.AddNew(oMissing, oMissing);

rsKR.Fields["F1"].Value = someObject.Id;
rsKR.Fields["F2"].Value = someObject.Name;

rsKR.Update(oMissing, oMissing);
rsKR.MoveFirst();

VB6Project.ClassAPI objVBAPI = new VB6Project.ClassAPI();
objVBAPI.InsertIntoDBFunction(rsKR);
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I have tried to call VB6 dll from .NET service and that went well, but I get exception when VB6 gets to the stage of inserting data in database.

Comment: So other functions in your Vb6 DLL work ok and it falls over when it tries to work insert data into your database?

Comment: yes, that is exactly what happens

Comment: Is your VB6 DLL COM+ enabled?

Comment: I'm not so good when it comes to VB6, how do I check that?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't do what you need to do from .Net?

Comment: Can you include the code that you used in .Net to call your VB6 component?

Comment: yes, very complicated calculations are done in the VB6 dll, these calculations are used by a system, so we don't want to do the same complicated calculations twice in order to minimize the risk of making mistakes and bugs.

Comment: I hate complicated calculations, how complicated could the complicated calculations be? Surely they can't be so complicated that you can't port the complicated calculation over to .NET. Who knows, maybe when you're going through them, you can make them less complicated?

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is use the .Net `TransactionScope` object to wrap all of your operations which you want to rollback in case of an exception. You also need to make sure that you VB6 component is running in COM+ Services, and has transactions enabled.

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required,
        new TransactionOptions(), EnterpriseServicesInteropOption.Full))
{
    dotNetDatabaseOperations(); //call whatever .net code here
    comProxy.comMethod(); //call to your VB6 component with interop wrapper

    scope.Complete();
} //if any exception happens in either .net or COM,
  //entire transaction will be rolled back here
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, my long day has just ended, I will try that tommorrow and give you feedback on how it goes.

Comment: Goodluck, feel free to add any followup questions here and I'll try to help.

Comment: If the transaction is *starting* in VB, or VBA, and *not* running in MTS, is that possible?